# Is it possible to split a database result by date using array_split?

Tags: php

I don't know if this can be done or not. I have a over 1000 rows being returned from the database and would like to split them by date using array_split after they've been returned. The dates are in the form of unix timestamps.

What I want to do is page these results by date. If this can be done, can someone give me a small example or point me in the direction I need to go in?

Comment: 1. Try to do it on DB side. 2. Show examples

Answer (score 0):

1. You need select new field which convert the format from timestamp to date string, and sort by it
2. loop through the result set, when the date is different of previous value, then create a sub array

PHP Code and SQL (PS: you must order by 'create_date' firstly)

**PS: the `group_by` function does not really grouping the whole data set!!**

```
$sql = " SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(create_timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') as create_date FROM some_table order by create_date asc";

$result = mysqli_query($dblink, $sql);

$grouped = group_by($result, 'create_date');


function group_by($inArray, $keyName) {
    if (is_array($inArray) && count($inArray)>0) {
        $cabinet = array();
        $tempBox = array();
        $prevoius_value = $inArray[0][$keyName];
        for($b=0;$b<count($inArray);$b++){
            $box = $inArray[$b];
            if ($prevoius_value != $box[$keyName]){
                array_push($cabinet, $tempBox);
                $tempBox = array();
                $prevoius_value = $box[$keyName];
            }
            array_push($tempBox, $box);
        }
         array_push($cabinet, $tempBox);
         return $cabinet;
    }
}
```

Here is the sample result:

```
$result = array(
    [0] => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'One',
        'create_timestamp' => '123456789',
        'create_date' => '2014-04-02'
    ),

    [1] => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Two',
        'create_timestamp' => '123456789',
        'create_date' => '2014-04-03'
    ),

    [2] => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Three',
        'create_timestamp' => '123456789',
        'create_date' => '2014-04-03'
    ),

    [3] => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Four',
        'create_timestamp' => '123456789',
        'create_date' => '2014-04-04'
    ),
);

$grouped = array(
    [0] => array(
        [0] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'One',
            'create_timestamp' => '123456789',
            'create_date' => '2014-04-02'
        )
    ),

    [1] => array(
        [0] => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Two',
            'create_timestamp' => '123456789',
            'create_date' => '2014-04-03'
        ),

        [1] => array(
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'Three',
            'create_timestamp' => '123456789',
            'create_date' => '2014-04-03'
        )
    ),

    [2] => array(
        [0] => array(
            'id' => 4,
            'name' => 'Four',
            'create_timestamp' => '123456789',
            'create_date' => '2014-04-04'
        )
    ),
);
```